import error on a discord bot from github
btw i have like no code experence this is a project for my club discord server abt meeting time and dates ect
original creator of the fork
https://github.com/RichardHladik/MailBot
my files in vscode
error i tried writing it differently but that didnt work
PS C:\Users\jp518\OneDrive\Documents\vscode> & C:/Users/jp518/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe c:/Users/jp518/OneDrive/Documents/vscode/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/jp518/OneDrive/Documents/vscode/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from config import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'imap_host'

main code
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import os
import email
import email.policy
import discord
import asyncio
from aioimaplib import aioimaplib
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser
from config import (
    imap_host,
    user,
    passwd,
    mail_channel_id,
    token,
)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
imap_host = imap_host.split(":")


def get_text_selectolax(html):
    """
    parsing HTML from email and returning crucial parts as TEXT
    """
    tree = HTMLParser(html)
    if tree.body is None:
        return None
    for tag in tree.css("script"):
        tag.decompose()
    for tag in tree.css("style"):
        tag.decompose()
    text = tree.body.text(separator="\n")
    return text


def strip_ending(t, pattern):
    if t.endswith(pattern):
        t = t[: -len(pattern)]
    return t


def simple_format(msg):
    msg = msg.replace("\n>\n", "\n> \n")
    msg = strip_ending(msg, "\n>")
    return msg


async def chunkize(channel, msg):
    LIMIT = 2000
    for i in range(0, len(msg), LIMIT):
        await channel.send(msg[i : i + LIMIT])


async def idle_loop(host, port, user, password):
    """
    This will loop to get new emails and send them to "mail_channel_id"
    """
    imap_client = aioimaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host=host, port=port, timeout=30)
    await imap_client.wait_hello_from_server()
    await imap_client.login(user, password)
    await imap_client.select()
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    while True:
        # only get emails which we haven't read
        mail_channel = client.get_channel(mail_channel_id)

        status, data = await imap_client.search("(UNSEEN)")
        data = [d.decode() for d in data]
        for i in data[0].split():
            print("Fetching msg {i}")
            typ, mail = await imap_client.fetch(str(i), "(RFC822)")
            mail_msg = email.message_from_bytes(mail[1], policy=email.policy.SMTP)
            mail_channel = client.get_channel(mail_channel_id)

            msg_header = (
                f"**From:** {mail_msg['from']}\n"
                f"**Subject:** {mail_msg['subject']}\n"
                f"**To:** {mail_msg['to']}\n"
                f"**Date:** {mail_msg['date']}"
            )

            msg_body = []
            for part in mail_msg.walk():
                if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                    message = "\n".join(
                        part.get_payload(decode=True).decode().splitlines()
                    )

                    message = get_text_selectolax(message).strip("\n")
                    message = simple_format(message)
                    msg_body.append(message)

                if part.get_content_maintype() == "multipart":
                    continue

                if part.get("Content-Disposition") is None:
                    continue

            msg = msg_header + "\n\n" + "\n".join(msg_body)
            await chunkize(mail_channel, msg)

        idle = await imap_client.idle_start(timeout=60)
        print((await imap_client.wait_server_push()))
        imap_client.idle_done()
        await asyncio.wait_for(idle, 30)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(client))


def on_error(event, *args, **kwargs):
    message, *_ = args
    print(message)
    os._exit(1)


async def main():
    async with client:
        client.loop.create_task(
            idle_loop(imap_host[0], int(imap_host[1]), user, passwd)
        )
        client.loop.set_exception_handler(on_error)
        await client.start(token)


asyncio.run(main())

config file
imap_host = "imap.gmail.com:993"
user = "redacted@gmail.com"
passwd = "redacted"
mail_channel_id = redacted
token = "redacted"

any help would be greatly apreceated

Probably there is another config.py file that is imported instead of the right one.

i just fixed it by renaming the config to config.py

renamed the config file config.py in vscode

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
